# Camunda redeploy dmn java way

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, camunda

Deployed my dmn.

```
 ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration
        .createStandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration()
        .setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:./camunda-db/process-engine;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000")
        .setDatabaseSchemaUpdate("true")
        .setJobExecutorActivate(true)
        .buildProcessEngine();
    
    processEngine.getRepositoryService()
        .createDeployment()
        .addClasspathResource("dmn/test.dmn")
        .deploy();
```

I would like to deploy new version of the same dmn. I found decision only with rest api way like in this link,

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.9/reference/rest/deployment/post-redeploy-deployment/

i would like to make it using java api way (using ProcessEngine or something from Camunda library). It is possible?

Comment: What is now exactly the question? Or issue you're facing? "I would like to deploy new version of the same dmn." What does this mean? Is it a new version or the same? Models which are equal to a previous version are ignored on deployment afaik.

Comment: I would like to deploy a new different version of my dmn. but with versioning support

Comment: @Zelldon i found rest api way, but i would like to do it using java code